# jquery mobile link from listview does not reload the page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have been learning a lot about jquery mobile and the mechanics on how it handles events and page reloads. I am having an issue where some click events are not firing more than once but it depends on how I approach the page.

One of those ways is when I have a link in a listview widget as apposed to a link by itself. I have noticed that when I click on a link from a listview then it does not reload the new page but instead just reloads the content. Therefore the click event is only triggered once since it is not reloaded.

```
<div class="container tickets">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">
        <li><a href="/link1/index.php" data-ajax="false">Link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/link2/index.php" data-ajax="false">Link2</a></li>
        <? } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If I have just a hard link like

```
<a href="/link1/index.php">Link1</a>
```

Then it will reload the page and the click event will fire every time.

My question is it better to leave `data-ajax="false"` off the link in the listview to allow a smoother transition or is there any issue with just causing a page reload every time. And if I do decide to leave `data-ajax="false"` out of the picture how can I get the click event to fire every time?

From what I understand using `pagebeforeshow` for my event trigger should allow for my click event to fire every time even with the smooth transition, but it is not. Am I missing something here?

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.change_status', function() {
        // do stuff
    })
})
```

Comment: a detailed explanation of the single-page model: http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1858265&seqNum=2